# Responsive on Wordpress not working

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Hello I'm building this site on wordpress: [MY SITE](http://wantagh.demosite.us/). The website is built in Wordpress everything looks perfect. However the follow us along with the 3 icons when you look at it in the monbile (shrink the browser) it gets really huge and crazy. Not sure how to fix it I tried everything.

Right now the header is split up into 3 sections each with a class ".col.-xs-12 .col-md-4" That way when its mobile they stack up on each other. In the first section (the follow us) I have another div with col-xs-4 I believe.

I know this is probably an easy fix. Thank you!

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site 
that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once 
the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that 
demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see 
[Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is the rule from `main.css` that's causing the problem.

`.col-md-4 .social-fixed { width: 45% }`

It makes the icons blow up to be 45% of the width of their parent elements. You probably want to assign the width to the parent class, i.e. `.col-md-4` or find some other way to resize the container.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adding `col-xs-4` to them?

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4 widget1">...</div>
<div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4 widget2">...</div>
<div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4 widget3">...</div>
```